# Get row id for inserted row in sqldelight

Tags: sqlite, sqldelight

I'm trying to use sqldelight to insert an item, but to also return the id of the item after it's inserted. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in sqldelight.

I can call something like `SELECT last_insert_rowid();` after I do the insert, but is this the best way to move forward?

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add this command to your .sq file:

```
lastInsertRowId:
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
;
```

And it will return you an `id` of last inserted row.

Please refer to this [issue on Github](https://github.com/square/sqldelight/issues/1015) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was looking for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked 5 years ago, but is still relevant))

My solution is that, within one transaction, we insert data and immediately request the maximum value of the PRIMARY KEY field.

Here's my example.

**DayliForecast.sq:**

```
import kotlin.Int;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DailyForecast (
    pid             INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
    year            INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    month           INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    day_of_month    INTEGER AS Int  NOT NULL,
    hours_of_sun    REAL            NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    forecast_key    TEXT            NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS DailyForecastDate ON DailyForecast (
    year            DESC,
    month           DESC,
    day_of_month    DESC,
    forecast_key    DESC
);

insert:
REPLACE INTO DailyForecast
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);

lastPid:
SELECT MAX(pid) FROM DailyForecast;

selectByDateRange:
SELECT * FROM DailyForecast
    WHERE
        forecast_key = ?
        AND year >= ?
        AND month >= ?
        AND day_of_month >= ?
        AND year <= ?
        AND month <= ?
        AND day_of_month <= ? LIMIT 5;
```

**ForecastDbRepositoryImpl:**

```
class ForecastDbRepositoryImpl(private val database: Database): ForecastDbRepository() {

    override suspend fun insertDailyForecast(dailyForecast: DailyForecast): Long {
        return database.transactionWithResult {
            insertForecast(dailyForecast)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun insertDailyForecast(dailyForecasts: List<DailyForecast>): List<Long> {
        return database.transactionWithResult {
            dailyForecasts.map { insertForecast(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun insertForecast(dailyForecast: DailyForecast): Long {
        database.dayliForecastQueries.insert(
            pid = dailyForecast.pid.takeIf { it >= 0L },
            year = dailyForecast.year,
            month = dailyForecast.month,
            day_of_month = dailyForecast.day_of_month,
            hours_of_sun = dailyForecast.hours_of_sun,
            forecast_key = dailyForecast.forecast_key
        )
        return database.dayliForecastQueries.lastPid().executeAsOne().MAX ?: 0L
    }
}
```

I just tested this myself and it works great!

Important addition. If you want auto-increment to work in this example, you need to use just such a constructor: `REPLACE INTO DailyForecast      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);` And pass null to argument named pid

For everything to work as it should, you **cannot use** the following insertion description:

```
insert:
REPLACE INTO DailyForecast
     VALUES ?;
```

Since in the generated class the pid field is not nullable!